# default vi in zsh and bash are different

Tags: linux, bash, vim, shell, zsh

I have a root and a wheel user in CentOS 7. The default shell for root and the wheel are bash and zsh respectively. The PATH is:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

/usr/local/sbin is empty, and I defined in /usr/local/bin that `vi->/bin/vimx`

Here is what confuses me:
In root, when I use vi, it automatically starts as vimx (as I expect)

```
which vi
/usr/local/bin/vi
```

However in wheel user, when I use vi, it use vim,

```
which vi                                                                                                                                                                                               
vi=vim
```

I checked all the directories in the PATH and the ~/.zshrc file, but I don't see anywhere defines such vi=vim. I'm confused where this "vi=vim" could be defined.

p.s. I use oh.my.zsh for zsh

----update----

I use alias command and find out "vi=vim" is defined, along with a bunch of other aliased commands, but I still don't get it where those aliasing are written.

Comment: Already answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question. My question is where "alias vi=vim" is defined. However, reading that threat helped me understand the usage of which and where. Thanks!